# How detect Home or Back key ( soft or physical ) pressed in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I writing a game for android with libgdx  every time i pressed Back key of phone the app completely exit but i want when i press Back key the game pause , How can i handle this ? in fact how can i detect when this key(s) is pressed :

My last try was : `Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)` but it didn't work.